# Showing divergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right)$ where $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

I am trying to prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right)$$ diverges, for any $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$.

I tried showing this by taking the Taylor expansionof $\log(1+\epsilon)$ around $0$ up to order $N$, where $N$ is the minimal integer such that $\alpha N >1$, then
substituting $\epsilon = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}$.

This resulted in the sum of the following libnitz serieses + some convergent series (it converges because $\alpha N >1$) + the remainder, and they all converge:

\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} (\log(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha})\\
=&\sum\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}-\sum\frac{1}{2k^{2\alpha}}+\dots+\sum(-1)^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{\alpha N}\cdot N}+\sum R_N\left(\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right)
\end{align*}

which is clearly in contradiction with the sum of the logs diverging

Comment: The second sum on the RHS diverges because $2\alpha\lt 1$

Comment: $\log (1+x)=x-x^{2}/2+...+(-1)^{N}\frac {x^{N}}N+o(x^{N+1})$ Choose $N$ such that  $\alpha (N+1)>1$.

Comment: If the claimed result is true then it is a little bit surprising, because $\log (1+x) \approx x,$ and so $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right) \approx \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}$ which converges because it is an alternating sequence of decreasing terms. I guess the point is that the difference between $ \log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right)$ and $\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}$ is sufficiently large to make the sum of the former diverge.

Comment: The name is "Leibniz", not "libnitz".

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ \log(1+x)=x+O(x^2) $$
one has
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{2\alpha}}\right)\right]. $$
Noting that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^\alpha}$ converges for $\alpha>0$ and that $\sum k^{-2\alpha}$ converges if $\alpha>\frac12$ and diverges if $\alpha\le\frac12$, one concludes that the series converges if $\alpha>\frac12$ and diverges if $\alpha\le\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Use **General Leibniz's Test:**   if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ \mbox{converges}\iff
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})\ \mbox{converges},$$
and they have the same sum.

**Proof:** Let
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k,\quad T_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{2k-1}+a_{2k}),$$
then
$$S_{2n}=T_n=S_{2n+1}-a_{2n+1}.$$
this implies they have the same convergence and have the same sum.

> > The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^\alpha}\right)$$ is convergent if and only if $\alpha>\frac12$.

**Proof:** By the **General Leibniz's Test**, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^\alpha}\right)$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^\alpha}\right)
+\ln\left(1+\frac{-1}{(2n)^\alpha}\right)\right]$$
have the same convergence. Note that
$$\begin{align*}
0\leq\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^\alpha}\right)
   +\ln\left(1+\frac{-1}{(2n)^\alpha}\right)
&=\ln\frac{((2n-1)^\alpha+1)((2n)^\alpha-1)}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha}\\
&\sim\frac{(2n)^\alpha-(2n-1)^\alpha-1}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha}\\
&=\frac{(2n)^\alpha-(2n-1)^\alpha}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha}-\frac{1}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha},
\end{align*} $$ and
$$\frac{(2n)^\alpha-(2n-1)^\alpha}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha}\sim\frac{\alpha}{(2n)^{\alpha+1}},\
\frac{1}{(2n-1)^\alpha(2n)^\alpha}\sim\frac{1}{(2n)^{2\alpha}},\ n\to\infty.$$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{(2n)^{\alpha+1}}$ converges if and only if $\alpha>0$,
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^{2\alpha}}$ converges if and only if $\alpha>\frac12.$

So $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^\alpha}\right)$ is convergent if and only if $\alpha>\frac12$.